# The party model, permissions, customers and staff

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, authorization, access-control

We are using a party model for a booking application, so that customers and staff effectively share the same table in the database.

Previously customers could only 'book' an appointment if they paid and if a slot was available. Now, we want to create a `premium_customer` type role so that customers can make bookings without paying and even if there is no availability.

Does it make sense to add customers to a single security model, such as in an ACL or RBAC?

- If so, do we introduce roles called `normal_customer` and `premium_customer` alongside our `reception` and `duty_manager` and other staff roles?
- If not, should there be a separate security model for website users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is fair to create another role to record premium customer

Comment: Simple one line answer, but closest to the truth.

Answer (score 2):

As I don't know all your requirements, i can't give you a definitive solution, but your Approach to create a role could be correct i many cases. However, you could also create a "Subscription", wich could have start- and end date.